# vs code powershell says like this

Tags: node.js, express

SET NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js
Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'server.js'.
At line:1 char:1

- SET NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand
  ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

cross-env npm is a package for cross platform handling of environment settings